# Не подключается MySql к WEB приложению на Java

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, веб-программирование, jdbc

Пишу веб - приложение на Java для курсовой работы.
При запуске выдает ошибку

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [tanat.servlet.IceFloeList] in context with path [/SalvageService] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at tanat.database.DBUtils.queryIceFloe(DBUtils.java:19)
    at tanat.servlet.IceFloeList.doGet(IceFloeList.java:47)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
```

Ругаеться как я понял на этот класс

```
package tanat.database;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import tanat.beans.IceFloe;

public class DBUtils {

    public static List<IceFloe> queryIceFloe(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "SELECT `id`, `name_ice_floe`, ` number_of_fishermen` "
                + "FROM ice_floe ORDER BY 'number_of_fishermen' DESC;";

        PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);  //на эту строку ругается
        ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();
        List<IceFloe> list = new ArrayList<IceFloe>();

//пробывал через статмент ничего не меняеться
//      Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
//      ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("ID");
            String name = rs.getString("Name");
            int numberOfFishermen = rs.getInt("NumberOfFishermen");
            IceFloe iceFloe = new IceFloe();
            iceFloe.setId(id);
            iceFloe.setNameIceFloe(name);
            iceFloe.setNumberOfFishermen(numberOfFishermen);
            list.add(iceFloe);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static IceFloe findIceFloe(Connection conn, String code) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "Select a.Code, a.Name, a.Price from Product a where a.Code=?";

        PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstm.setString(1, code);

        ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            String name = rs.getString("Name");
            int numberOfFishermen = rs.getInt("NumberOfFishermen");
            IceFloe iceFloe = new IceFloe();
            iceFloe.setNameIceFloe(name);
            iceFloe.setNumberOfFishermen(numberOfFishermen);
            return iceFloe;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void updateIceFloe(Connection conn, IceFloe iceFloe) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "Update Product set Name =?, Price=? where Code=? ";

        PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pstm.setInt(1, iceFloe.getId());
        pstm.setString(2, iceFloe.getnameIceFloe());
        pstm.setInt(3, iceFloe.getNumberOfFishermen());

        pstm.executeUpdate();
    }

    public static void insertIceFloe(Connection conn, IceFloe iceFloe) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "Insert into Product(Code, Name,Price) values (?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pstm.setInt(1, iceFloe.getId());
        pstm.setString(2, iceFloe.getnameIceFloe());
        pstm.setInt(3, iceFloe.getNumberOfFishermen());

        pstm.executeUpdate();
    }

    //удаление льдины
    //по идее нужно реализовать автоматическое удаление если количество рыбаков становиться равным 0
    public static void deleteIceFloe(Connection conn, String code) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "Delete From Product where Code= ?";

        PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pstm.setString(1, code);

        pstm.executeUpdate();
    }

}
```

помогите пожалуйста, уже 3 день вожусь, а времени мало осталось)
если понадобиться глянуть другие классы: https://bitbucket.org/pahan-titan/salvageservice/src
Зарание, спасибо

Comment: Видимо в `conn` передается `null` из `IceFloeList.java:47`. Это только одна ошибка? Мне кажется у вас еще ошибка при соединении с БД присутствует, поэтому и `null` вместо `Connection` вы получаете.

Comment: если у вас ругается код на строку PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql) и летит NullPointerException, то тут вариантов вообще никаких. Единственный возможный - переменная conn ссылается в никуда. Вы получаете эту переменную в виде аргумента метода Connection conn. Смотрите код, откуда вызывается этот метод. Он передает вам null в переменной conn. И проверить это просто - добавьте перед строчкой, которая бросает исключение, System.out.println(conn); Если увидите в консоли заветный null, то все сказанное полностью подтверждается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку вы получаете null в аргументах указанного метода в переменной типа Connection, то и рыть стоит в торону класса, соединения раздающего.

Посему сделайте так...
Для начала подключите в качестве jdbc-драйвера вот этот
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.45

Насколько я понял, класс, раздающий коннекты MySQLConnUtils

Напишите его таким образом

```
import com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MySQLConnUtils {

    public static Connection getMySQLConnection() throws SQLException {
        String hostName = "localhost";
        String dbName = "salvage_service";
        String dbPort = "3306";
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "qweqwe123123";
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + hostName + ":" + dbPort + "/" + dbName;

        Driver driver = new FabricMySQLDriver();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
        return DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, userName, password);

    }

}
```

Если не получится , то пишите, какая ошибка летит

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло.
Правда теперь данные не выводит в js страницу(

Comment: ну, это уже другая проблема. контролируйте программу поэтапно. выведите в консоль данные, которые возвращает бд. потом смотрите, что с ними делает бекенд, а уже потом смотрите, что передается на фронт и что происходит там. база данных живет по своим законам, бекенд по своим, а фронт по своим. селяви))